# How to fix "married" light switches that have been wired in series?

Tags: wiring

I have a light switch at the top of my staircase and another at the bottom. I would like to be able to use either light switch to turn on/off the light.

However instead they seem to be wired in series in that BOTH the switches have to be on in order for the light to work.

Is there any non-intrusive way to rewire this so that both switches can be used to toggle the light?

Comment: I would bet that the wiring is there for a pair of 3-way switches. (Possibly someone replaced one or both switches and put in a 2-way switch.) Are both switches currently in place 3-way switches? Three-way switches will not have the words  "on" and "off" on the toggle like a 2-way switch.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring inside the switch boxes?

Comment: If there are two 3-way switches present, it could be simply that they are not connected properly for standard mechanical switches. But if the correct wiring is not present for standard mechanical 3-way switches, I think there are smart switches that can provide the function wanted.

Comment: Probably -- but we need to see the topology of the wiring in both switch boxes.  That will decide exactly how to allocate the available wires.

Comment: You were exactly right @JimStewart, one of the switches was a 2-way with a traveller wire screwed into the ground. Replaced it with a three-way and it works properly now. Thank god, I was afraid I would have to rip open the wall.

Comment: Interesting . . . without drawing a diagram I'd suppose that this could have resulted in an energized switch ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to rewire it to work the way you want if they are three-way switches.

Here's a diagram from Wikipedia:
[image: Wiring diagram showing two switches controlling one light]

Here's what the behaviour should be:

```
Switch 1    Switch 2    Light is
On          Off         On
Off         On          On
Off         Off         Off
On          On          Off
```

[See further explanation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#Two_locations)

Comment: Thank you, luckily the wiring behind the walls were done to support a 3 way switch, but the previous owners used a 2 way switch for one of them instead of a 3 way and screwed in one of the traveller wires to the ground of the switch _facepalm_. In any case, it works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my suggestion is very ghetto.

I'd buy [Ikea Tradfri](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/lighting/smart-lighting/) or similar (countless options in market using also [433mhz signal](https://www.bol.com/nl/p/klikaanklikuit-draadloos-dimbare-led-lamp-aled-2709/9200000056620561/?Referrer=ADVNLGOO002042-G-54537195030-S-375813732464-9200000056620561&gclid=Cj0KCQjwv-DaBRCcARIsAI9sba-CwAqp_ApjULGAiiyCNc9qqREFJw-P-7gCxAvRFSmT9OFSGUZ-_7QaAkKLEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) or other) and then put the lamp cables so that it is ALWAYS on (and no interaction allows to turn it off from the old switches) and use tradfri (or 433 switches) for ON / OFF.

If you choose the 433mhz path you can use switchs like [this](https://www.klikaanklikuit.nl/nl/producten/awst-8800-draadloze-wandschakelaar.html) or use your curent switches with [this](https://www.klikaanklikuit.nl/nl/producten/awmt-230-ingebouwde-mini-zender.html) hardware.

Good luck! :)